# Sortable table not working as intended

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Trying to follow the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?view=comments) about sortable tables, but running into an issue of the tables either not sorting as intended, or failing to load the page.

The only way I can seem to get it working is by hard coding a string into the order function. I can get the query to be passed in the url, just seems like no action is being taken. Code below:

AdminController.rb

```
class AdminController < ActionController::Base
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

def partners
  @partners = []
  DashboardPartner.order(params[:sort]).pluck(:partner_id).uniq.each do |id|
................

def sort_column
  DashboardPartner.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

application.html.haml

```
%li= sortable 'name', 'Name'
%li= sortable 'day', 'Day'
%li= sortable 'month', 'Month'
%li= sortable 'year', 'Year'
%li= sortable 'alltime', 'Alltime'
/ %li= link_to "Name", sort: "name"
/ %li= link_to "Day", sort: "day"
/ %li= link_to "Month", sort: "month"
/ %li= link_to "Year", sort: "year"
/ %li= link_to "Alltime", sort: "alltime"
```

When I use sortable here, I get an error "undefined local variable or method `sort_column'". When I use link_to, nothing goes into order.

application_helper.rb

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}
end
```

Comment: Have you tried copying / moving the `sort_column` and `sort_direction` methods into `application_helper.rb` to see if it finds them there?

Comment: @SRack Putting those methods into both controller and helped stopped the error, but nothing is sorting still

Comment: Great - that's one step forwards. Are you getting an error now? I'm not entirely sure, but I wonder if `column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"` is evaluating correctly. I'd wrap this in parenthesis to test it out, as follows: `(column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"`. As it is, I've a feeling it might evaluate `column == sort_column` outside of the ternary.

Comment: No errors now. Nothing changed after wrapping that line in parenthesis.

Comment: It seems to be falling back to the defaults in sort_column every time. So I think I'm having trouble with params[:sort] in some way.

Comment: I have the same error here. Railscasts teach to put methods "sort column" and "sort_direction" on controller as private.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your helper method and these lines on `sortable` method

```
direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"

link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}
```

it should

```
direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
link_to title, {sort: column, direction: direction}
```

then method will looks like

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, {sort: column, direction: direction}
end
```

If you need to use this search page you need to merge with current search result by adding `request.query_parameters.merge` this like below

```
link_to title, request.query_parameters.merge({sort: column, direction: direction})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but didnt change anything. Still resorting to defaults in the sort methods

Comment: I believe something is happening, that's working on my hand properly, you need to refactoring @oisinmcdaid